# Ubuntu Server Wifi without netplan

Tags: server, wireless, netplan

Ok, I am trying to setup Ubuntu Server on wifi as the place to keep it corded is not convenient. Is it possible to use network manager instead of setting up a netplan?

I do not want to mess with a netplan. The netplan is extremely messy as there is no format to follow, everyone has them setup differently, they are extremely picky and I keep getting an error on formatting or a no access point error. I also keep messing up my LAN and loosing connection, the only way to fix that is to reinstall at this point.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets: 
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      optional: true
        access-points:
          :network_ssid_name":
            password: "************"
```

Comment: This would be much easier with Ubuntu Desktop. Set that up with all the power profiles set to not shut the machine off and you’re golden 

Comment: Of course you can use Network Manager. 1) Simply install it (`sudo apt install network-manager`), then 2) Look up a good tutorial on how to use it's shell interface. There are lots out there. However, I eventually came to the conclusion that a longer network cable was faster and more reliable than WiFi; the afternoon I spent running the cable through walls was very much worthwhile.

Comment: @Matigo I agree BUT, ubuntu desktop no longer works with my wifi card an intel centrino wireless-n 2230 on wpa wpa2 networks. It also does not work with Jellyfin, my chosen media server. Although oddly server runs it flawlessly. I have yet to figure that one out.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 2):

Netplan is the default in server installations. In static configurations, it's not that difficult to configure. NetworkManager **could** be used instead, but would require the use of CLI tools to configure.

Your .yaml should look like this... I added renderer, removed trailing spaces, and corrected quotes and indentation for access-points and below...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "************"
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

To use wireless on a server installation, you need to install `wpasupplicant`. Temporarily connect via ethernet to be able to install it easily.

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install wpasupplicant`

`reboot`